# Parsing file, ignoring comments and blank lines

Tags: go

As the title says, I am trying to parse a file but ignore comments (started with `#`) or blank lines. I have tried to make a system for this, yet it always seems to ignore that it should be ignoring comments and/or blank lines.

```
lines := strings.Split(d, "\n")
var output map[string]bool = make(map[string]bool)

for _, line := range lines {
    if strings.HasPrefix(line, "#") != true {
        output[line] = true
    } else if len(line) > 0 {
        output[line] = true
    }
}
```

When run (this is part of a function), it outputs the following

```
This is the input ('d' variable):
Minecraft
Zerg Rush
Pokemon

# Hello

This is the output when printed ('output' variable):

map[Minecraft:true Zerg Rush:true Pokemon:true :true # Hello:true]
```

My issue here is that it still keeps the "" and "# Hello" values, meaning that something failed, something I haven't been able to figure out.

So, what am I doing wrong that this keeps the improper values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`len(line) > 0` will be true for the `"# Hello"` line, so it will get added to `output`.

Currently, you are adding lines that either don't start with a # *or* are not empty. You need to only add lines that satisfy both conditions:

```
if !strings.HasPrefix(line, "#") && len(line) > 0 {
    output[line] = true
}
```

Comment: a minor optimization would be `if len(line) > 0 && line[0] != '#' { ... }`